# Show Status Command by conexion SSH in viwe show me blank page

Tags: php, ssh, laravel-5

I need show  the result of my  status comand in a remote host  all is ok if  use echo to see the variable but to show in view  the layout
 welcome.blade showme blank page. i know that $variable have the fault
for the type of data but i dont have idea how fit the error Please
 help me

```
public function home()    
{
$variable=\SSH::into('production1')->run(['service sshd status'], function($line){
$result= $line.PHP_EOL;
$busco='Se está ejecutando openssh';
$pos = strpos($result, $busco);
 if ($pos === false){
$people=["todo bien"];
//echo "No se tiene conexion ssh";
//  return view('welcome',compact ('people'));
//return view('welcome')->with('people',$people);
return view('welcome')->withpeople($people);}
else{
   //echo "ok";

    $people=["todo mal"];
    return view('welcome')->withpeople($people);

}
});
}>
```

IT IS THE CODE IN CONTROLLER

//AND THE CODE POR WELCOME.BLADE

```
@foreach ($people as $person)
    <li>{{$person}} </li>
 @endforeach
```

Answer (score 1):

it is the aswer if something have the same dude

```
public function home()
{
$variable=\SSH::into('production1')->run(['service sshd status'],        function($line){
$this->output = $line.PHP_EOL;});
$result=$this->output;
 $busco='Se está ejecutando openssh';
 $pos = strpos($result, $busco);
if ($pos === false){
$people=["down"];
return view('welcome')->withpeople($people);}
else{
    $people=["up"];
    return view('welcome')->withpeople($people);
}
```

}